# Null Pointer issue using string::iterator in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2005, iterator

I am working with some legacy code.  The legacy code works in production mode in the following scenario.  I'm trying to build a command line version of the legacy code for testing purposes.  I suspect there is an environmental setting issue at work here, but I'm relatively new to C++ and Visual Studio (long time eclipse/java guy).

This code is attempting to read in a string from a stream.  It reads in a short, which in my debug scenario has a value of 11.  Then, it is supposed to read in 11 chars.  But this code craps out on the first char.  Specifically, in the `read` method below, `ptr` is null, and so the `fread` call is throwing an exception.  Why is `ptr` NULL?

Point of clarification, `ptr` becomes null between the operator>>(string) and operator>>(char) calls.

```
Mystream& Mystream::operator>>( string& str )
{
string::iterator                it;
short                           length;

*this >> length;

if( length >= 0 )
{
    str.resize( length );
    for ( it = str.begin(); it != str.end(); ++it )
    {
        *this >> *it;
    }
}

return *this;
}
```

The method for reading the short is here and looking at the file buffer etc. this looks like it is working properly.

```
Mystream& Mystream::operator>>(short& n )
{
    read( ( char* )&n, sizeof( n ) );
    SwapBytes( *this, ( char* )&n, sizeof( n ) );
    return *this;
}
```

Now, the method for reading in a char is here:

```
Mystream& Mystream::operator>>(char& n )
{
    read( ( char* )&n, sizeof( n ) );
    return *this;
}
```

and the read method is:

```
Mystream& Mystream::read( char* ptr, int n )
{
fread( (void*)ptr, (size_t)1, (size_t)n, fp );
return *this;
}
```

One thing I don't understand, in the string input method, the *it is a char right?  So why does the operator>>(char &n) method get dispatched on that line?  In the debugger, it looks like the *it is a 0, (although a colleague tells me he doesn't trust the 2005 debugger on such things) and thus, it looks like the &n is treated as a null pointer and so the read method is throwing an exception.

Any insights you can provide would be most helpful!

Thanks
John

ps. For the curious, `Swap` Bytes looks like this:

```
inline void SwapBytes( Mystream& bfs, char * ptr, int nbyte, int nelem = 1)
{ 
    // do we need to swap bytes?
if( bfs.byteOrder() != SYSBYTEORDER )
    DoSwapBytesReally( bfs, ptr, nbyte, nelem );
}
```

And `DoSwapBytesReally` looks like:

```
void DoSwapBytesReally( Mystream& bfs, char * ptr, int nbyte, int nelem )
{
    // if the byte order of the file
    // does not match the system byte order
    // then the bytes should be swapped
int i, n;
char temp;

#ifndef _DOSPOINTERS_
char *ptr1, *ptr2;
#else _DOSPOINTERS_
char huge *ptr1, huge *ptr2;
#endif _DOSPOINTERS_

int nbyte2;

nbyte2 = nbyte/2;

for ( n = 0; n < nelem; n++ ) 
{
    ptr1 = ptr;
    ptr2 = ptr1 + nbyte - 1;

    for ( i = 0; i < nbyte2; i++ ) 
    {
        temp = *ptr1;
        *ptr1++ = *ptr2;
        *ptr2-- = temp;
    }

    ptr += nbyte;
}
}
```

Comment: Where method that reads short?

Comment: You seem to believe that ’char &n’ syntax is somehow related to pointers. It isn't. It declares a reference. It gets bound to a ’char’ object ’*it’, as it should. Read about references in your favorite C++ book.

Comment: My insight: it'll probably be easier to throw this away and start over than try to fix such a mess.

Comment: @AndersK debugger verifies it is not null.  ptr is null in the read function.

Comment: @AndreyT Good.  Yes, that makes sense, but I don't understand why the value of ptr in read is null in this context.  Do you?

Comment: how does SwapBytes look like? It is the last the runs before reading the rest so maybe it does something fishy

Comment: @AndersK Added SwapBytes.  I don't think that's it.  But, reasonable question to ask, so I threw it in.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in `Mystream::read( char* ptr, int n )`, and walk back up the stack to see what values are getting passed and when/if `ptr` goes from being a valid pointer to a null pointer. Then you'll at least know the right general place to start looking.

Answer (score 2):

I'd throw out this mess and start over. Extrapolating from the code, if what you had actually worked, it would be roughly equivalent to something like this:

```
MyStream::operator>>(string &s) { 
    short size;

    fread((void *)&size, sizeof(size), 1, fP);
    size = ntohs(size); // oops: after reading edited question, this is really wrong.
    s.resize(size);
    fread((void *)&s[0], 1, size, fp);
    return *this;
}
```

In this case, delegating most of the work to other functions doesn't seem to have gained much -- this does the work more directly, but still isn't significantly longer or more complex than the original (if anything, I'd say rather the opposite).

Comment: `&s[0]` is not valid when string is zero length.

Comment: @john: Yes, this is assuming all the serialized strings are non-zero length. Of course, we don't know enough to be sure that's the case -- in fact, from looking at the code, I'd guess the people who knew forgot years ago (DOS pointers? really?!)

Comment: dont speak bad about the DOS people :) I am one of them 8-)

Comment: @AndersK: I'm not speaking badly about them, just pointing out that the code is clearly ancient, and appears to have at least a couple decades of "technical debt".

Comment: Yes, this is ancient code.  My issue is, this particular bit is tangential to the code of interest.  Moreover, if my assertion that this is an environmental setting issues (this code does work on the production system) I need to know that now, rather than rewrite tons of other code because I screwed up an environment.  There's about a million lines of code in this app that I'm working with.

Comment: In our company we call it "heritage code", apparently it has a nicer ring to it <g>

Answer (score 0):

I found a gray beard in the company who could explain what's going on to me.  (I had already spoken to 2 old timers so I figured I had covered the old timer avenue of attack.)  The code above is not ANSI compliant STL code.  In Visual Studio 2005, Microsoft first introduced STL and there were issues.  In particular older code that used to work would now fail in 2005 (I think 64bit mode may play a role in this as well.)  Because of this, code will not work in debug mode (but it will work in release mode).  One partial article is located here.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985982%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

The particular issue I saw has to do with the line:  `it = str.begin()` in the first method in the question.  `str` is an empty string.  So `str.begin()` is technically not defined.  Visual Studio treats this situation differently between debug and release modes.  (Can't do this in debug, you can do it in release.)

Bottom line, the gray beard suggested rewrite was exactly Jerry's.  Ironically, the gray beard had fixed this problem in several files, but neglected to check it into the mainline.  Uh oh.  That scares the &#$!! out of me.